# Number Guessing Game. Negative intergers

Tags: javascript

I'm making a guessing game using javascript. I did it correctly on the positive side but how would I do it on the negative side. I am trying to make a guess between 0 and -4 boiling from the random number.

```
else if(difference >= 0 && difference <= 4)
{
    $("#answerDiv").html("Boiling");   
}
else if(difference >= 0 && difference <= -4)
{
    $("#answerDiv").html("Boiling");
}
```

Comment: your condition is backwards.  your number would be *less* than 0 and *greater* than -4.

Comment: It will never be greater than 0 AND less than minus four. Do you mean less than zero and greater than minus four?

Comment: Should it be `else if(difference < 0 && difference >= -4)` the second one?

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation but I got it. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(second else-if:)* `>= 0` could be 1 ad `<= -4` could be `-5` :) 
You probably want

```
else if(difference < 0 && difference > -5) // One of -1, -2, -3, -4
```

note that you already use `>=0` (greater or **equal to** 0) in the first `else if`, so be cautious when matching again `=0` inside another statement. Rather avoid duplicate matches by
doing like I did `< 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
         else if(difference >= 0 && difference <= 4)
            {
             $("#answerDiv").html("Boiling");   
            }
         else if(difference <= 0 && difference >= -4)
            {
             $("#answerDiv").html("Boiling");   
            }
```